# Why do I have an error: 'Actions must be plain objects' using redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

So I'm using a search bar and redux toolkit to search for a movie that I type, my input looks like this:

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
<form>
          <input 
          type="search" 
          placeholder="Search for a movie..." 
          autoFocus
          onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)}/>
        </form>
```

My reducer:

```
const initialState: ISearchState = {
    searchQuery: '',
    searchPage: 1,
    searchResult: null,
    fetchStatus: null,
  };

  const API_BASE = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE;
  const TMDB_API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

const searchSlice = createSlice({
  name:'search',
  initialState,
  reducers:{},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchSearch.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.fetchStatus = FetchStatus.PENDING
      })
      .addCase(fetchSearch.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.fetchStatus = FetchStatus.SUCCESS
        // Add any fetched posts to the array
        state.searchResult = action.payload
      })
      .addCase(fetchSearch.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.fetchStatus = FetchStatus.FAILURE
        //state.error = action.error.message
      })
  }
})
```

My async thunk action:

```
export const fetchSearch = createAsyncThunk('search/fetchSearch', async ({page, query} : {page: number, query: string}) => {
  const response = await axios.get<ISearch<IMovie>>(`${API_BASE}/search/movie?api_key=${TMDB_API_KEY}&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=false`);
  console.log(response.data);
  return response.data;
});
```

And useEffect in my component:

```
useEffect(() =>{
    if(query.length > 0){
      dispatch(fetchSearch(query));
    }
  }, [query])
```

So as soon as I start typing I dispatch a function using a particular query, but then I have an error in console:

```
Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

It's weird I have similar async functions in other reducers where I just fetch data, but here I can't do it. Maybe it has to do with me using `input`

Comment: Have you set up your Redux store using `configureStore()` from redux-toolkit? It should add the `redux-thunk` middleware automatically. Looks like you are missing the `redux-thunk` middleware.

Comment: yes, as i said, i have similar redux thunk functions which fetch the data, and they look the same, but i only have a problem with this one..maybe it has something to do with `query`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of RTK do you have installed atm, and what version of `redux` along with that?  (You can find out with `npm ls @reduxjs/toolkit` and `npm ls redux`, or `yarn why redux` if you're using Yarn.) The latest versions of RTK should also include Redux 4.1+, and that has a newer and better error message that tells you what's being dispatched instead of an action object.